# $x^n/(1+x^n) $is monotonic

Tags: uniform-convergence, monotone-functions

$x^n/(1+x^n)$ is monotonic , $x \in R^+ $ , $n \in N$
tried solving it by differentiating but not getting feasible result,
also is there any other way of computation through which this can be solved easily?

any hint would be appreciated

Comment: Counterexample: n=2, x=-1,0,1, pos, 0, pos

Comment: You need parentheses, Svidi

Comment: yes x is non-negative terms

Comment: You still need parentheses. $x^n/1+x^n$ means $2x^n$.

Comment: You mean $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$?

Comment: Hint: $x^n/(1+x^n) = 1 - 1/(1+x^n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $n \in \mathbb {N}$ and $x \in \mathbb {R}_{+}$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \frac {{x}^{n}}{{x}^{n} + 1}
& = \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \Big( 1 - \frac {1}{{x}^{n} + 1} \Big) \\
& = \frac {1}{{\left( {x}^{n} + 1 \right)}^{2}} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} {x}^{n} = \frac {n {x}^{n - 1}}{{\left( {x}^{n} + 1 \right)}^{2}} > 0.
\end{align}
$$
So the function is monotonic.

Comment: but when x<1 its monotonic decreasing function?

Comment: @Svidi Runs, the derivative is positive even when $x \in \left( 0, 1 \right)$, so, of course, it is still increasing. (You can go and draw some Desmos graphs and see.)

Comment: i did, its decreasing

Comment: @Svidi Runs. That is weird. I got https://www.desmos.com/calculator/skau7h6t2h. The graph shows that it is increasing. (Or could it be that my interpretation is incorrect?)

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vlzbqregt4  , i tried this way

Comment: @Svidi Runs, I see. Your input was $y = {n}^{x} / \left( {n}^{x} + 1 \right)$ and not $y = {x}^{n} / \left( {x}^{n} + 1 \right)$. This explains. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r2oliiv2wy.

Comment: i understand, my point is if you take x=.5 then the expression becomes$ .5^n/(.5^n+1)$ which is decreasing function, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151554/discussion-between-simon-and-svidi-runs).

Answer (score 3):

A composition of monotonic functions is monotonic (even if one is increasing and the other is decreasing). Here the two functions are
$$x\mapsto x^n$$
and
$$x\mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$$

Comment: Just need to show the monotonicity of the second, which it is.